# select and highlight custom listview item

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to position custom listview item

```
listView.setSelection(itemIndex);
```

Selected item positioning on the top of the visible part of listview. But not highlighted. 
How can i set default highlight of the listview item (then disable highlight and select another one) without listview re-create

Thanks!

p.s. I know it was asked many times before but i did not understand how it works

**update**
not work on my android 2.2 (adt emulator and smartphone with android 2.2 froyo)

drawable/listselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/yellow" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="yellow">#ffff00</color>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

layout/list1.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/listselector"
    android:clickable="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html

Comment: please add this in selector.xml  <item android:drawable="@color/white" /> if the list does not change the color something is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need a selector add this to you layout in xml

```
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

and create a `selecor.xml` in `drawable` folder like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/red"/> 
 </selector>
```

and finaly at the `values` folder in the `colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="black">#000000</color> 
        <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
        <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    </resources>
```

and call

```
listView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

before

```
listView.setSelection(itemIndex);
```

Comment: it didnt work. after "listView.setSelection(itemIndex);" no listview item highlighed

Comment: i do it without setSelection in my case. just enter android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/selector" in your layout

Comment: did it. maybe it was adt emulator bug? (android sdk 2.2)

Comment: i will test it on my emulator and report you